# Stop Android Notification Bar From Appearing on Touch Events

Tags: java, android

I need help removing or modifying the correct motion or touch events from the services.jar that call the notification bar to appear. I have a full screen application that keeps getting interrupted by the appearance of the notification bar. I understand I won't be able to do this at the application level but need to decompile the services.jar and edit the code directly.

Comment: StackOverflow has not generally been a good resource for firmware modifications, such as what you are proposing. I can tell you that "decompile the services.jar and edit the code directly" has limited chance of success.

Comment: Are you just trying to hide the notification bar completely?  That can be done quite easily if so.  I will add an answer if you confirm what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: and what has the tag `javascript-events` to do with this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm way off base but, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".WhateverYourAppIs"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
...
```

if you go [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html)
and just control-f for `fullscreen`, it will show you all of the fullscreen options that are included with android. you just have to replace the `_` with `.`