# press button makes spinner visible in another screen

Tags: java, android, listener, spinner

I'm trying to code an onClickevent button on screen 1 that makes
a spinner visible or invisible, depends of the needs, on screen 2 as a result.

Knowing that on screen 1 there are several buttons which uses the same views 
or widgets on the second screen, I was thinking about it to use one screen for 
all these activities.

It would be nice if someone knows and explain to me how to solve this problem.

I will attach the java code just to look at it.

```
public class screen1 extends Activity {

    private View spinner1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen1);

        spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Button A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_A);

     // error output: Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener
            A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
        A.setOnClickListener(mVisibleListener);
        }   

                        @Override
// error output behind the line 'public void':The method onClick(View) of type screen1 must override or implement a supertype method

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.jack.test.SCREENMENU"));

            }
            OnClickListener mVisibleListener = new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    spinner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);{
        };    
                       // the rest is ok from here to down.
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some major glitches going on with the code in addition to what you are asking. Fortunately, if I understand you correctly, the thing you want is easy to fix:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
{
    if (need_is_met)
        {
        if (spinner1.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
}
```

`need_is_met` is a boolean ... thats as far as i could get with your statement "depends of the needs"

as far as the rest of your code, it should read like this:

```
public class screen1 extends Activity
    {

    private View spinner1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
        boolean need_is_met = true; // you can change this or have it set based on something later if you want
        spinnerAutomerk = findViewById(R.id.spinnerAutomerk);
        button_A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_A);

        button_A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
                {
                if (need_is_met)
                    {
                    if (spinnerAutomerk.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
                        spinnerAutomerk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    else
                spinnerAutomerk.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

something like that. i took out all the `requestWindowFeature`, `windowFlag` etc because it is much neater to put this into your manifest:

```
...
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    >
  <activity
        android:name=".Screen1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
...
```

that last line, the theme bit, will set you up with any one of a number of themes (such as dark, light, transparent etc. just got to [R.style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html) and ctrl-F for `theme` and youll see there is a number to choose from. similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285470/stop-android-notification-bar-from-appearing-on-touch-events/6286208#6286208) they can kill the title and notification bar, if you wish.
also i didnt to set `net_is_met` to something because i dont know what the rest of your code is about.

Comment: Thanks hooray, looks really more tidy. As for your solution I try to

Comment: glady, if you leave that out, then every single time the button is clicked, it will toggle the visibility of the spinner. also, if you wanted `'if (need_is_met)'` to look like code, you have to use ` instead of ' (its the top left key next to the 1. please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks again, I get it now (I hope..lol). And I do have a lot of questions, but step-by-step learning is my style. Just to make sure that I understand the material of Android dev. well. Now it's time to implement your solution. You will hear from me. Ciao

Comment: haha well if it helps you, i would love if you selected my answer as correct :) also if you have any further questions about this or other things you post on stackoverflow, if you link to the new question in the comments here, i'll try to help.

Comment: Yeah, I will select it gladly, the minute it works. btw about the rest of the code ....it's just identical with the button_A configuration code in total of 12 buttons.

Comment: Yep, an error came up. I get one error saying 'Syntax error on token "DialogInterface", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token' on this line 'public void onClick(DialogInterface, int which)'.

Comment: hrm, ill look at it when i get home from work, i typed all that off the top of my head so i prolly messed something up.

Comment: yeah, you were sort of right, i dont know why i had that in there, its supposed to read `public void onClick(View v)` i fixed it in my answer, let me know how that runs

Comment: 2 errors came up: 1. 'if (need_is_met) cannot be resolved to a variable. 2. if (spinnerAutomerk.getVisibility()== View.INVISIBLE)
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); I get 'view cannot be resolved'. Hope you find the answers.

Comment: ok now i updated my answer, need_is_met has been declared and set (if you told me what your app was doing this could be more efficient), and i am assuming that your spinner is called `spinnerAutomerk` because that is the name you used in the comment. but, other than that, this problem should easily be resolved today.

Comment: As you know I have 12 buttons in screen 1. They can use the same screen 2, because it's a fill form. So that I make a spinner or a textview (in)visible or 'gone'. otherwise I have to make 12 fill forms screens. And that is a little bit too much. After filling the form I would like to save the input data and share it with other users via 'cloud', webservice or whatever is the best to function.(this will be one of the hardiest thing to achieve, I think). Now I will try to do your idea...later

Comment: If I want the second button to behave like the first one. Is this the way to do it...see underneath implementation:

Comment: i don't see your code, but yes, it would just be just a matter of changing spinnerAutomerk to whatever your other spinners are and changing button_A to button_B etc.

Comment: Hi hooray, seems that my example went wrong. Btw I did some testing and didn't work at all.

Comment: can you edit your question to reflect your code; i want to help you but its hard for me to read code that isnt formatted correctly.

Comment: Sorry Hooray, I tried the markdown formatting, but didn't work. If you know another way let me know. Anyhow, what I want to show you is exactly putting the same code for spinnerAutomerk for spinnerAutomerk2 in the same class. If this doesn't work, maybe an other option is to let it the button the spinner  "gone". I already have a screen 2 activity with 2 spinners. I just want one of the other dissapear with "gone".

Comment: can you copy the code you have (formatted or not) into your question? i just don't think im understanding what you are trying to ask.

Comment: what errors are you getting? is there anyway you just send me a copy of your code, say via dropbox or something?

Comment: Hooray, send me your email for the dropbox. grtz. Jack

Comment: or try with this public link and btw it's a Wordpad ext.   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32310710/error%20java.odt

Answer (score 0):

First off all you need to have screen2 as another activity if you want it to open when clicked and show the spinner (not sure if that is exactly what you meant).

You should use intents to switch to screen2's activity. There a billion examples on how to do that if you google it.

You would use a Boolean to check if certain requirements are met or not:

```
Boolean Reqs = false;
If(req_met){
    Reqs = true;
} else {
    Reqs = false;
}
```

Use that type of format then check if Reqs is true or not when sending the intent to see if the spinner is visible or not (I would use another intent for that)

Comment: Thanks Brandon, yes I already have a screen2. I'm gonna try your solution also.